# Como adicionar logo num box de login boostrap?

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite! Como faço para adicionar uma logo num login-box? Estou tentando adicionar no meu site, mas não estou conseguindo.

Página em questão: http://tratspay.com/app/login.html

insira o código aqui

```
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-box-body">

<img src="app/dist/img/logo-trats-mini.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">

    <h3 class="login-box-msg">Faça o seu Login</h3><br>

    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control sty1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control sty1" placeholder="Senha">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">
              Salvar Senha </label>
            <a href="recuperar-senha.html" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Esqueceu a senha?</a> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 m-t-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Acessar Conta</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col --> 
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="social-auth-links text-center">

      </div>
    <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

    <div class="m-t-2">Ainda não possui uma conta? <a href="criar-conta.html" class="text-center"><strong> Cadastre-se</strong></a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do Bootstrap que vc está usando?? Reparei que no seu código já tem uma tag IMG o que deveria fazer aparecer a imagem. Vc j´verificou se está aparecendo algum erro na página acusando se a imagem não foi encontrada ou algo do tipo? Se possível explique melhor o problema, sua pergunta não está muito clara...

Answer (score -1):

Basicamente é só inserir a tag IMG onde quiser e formatar de acordo. Nesse exemplo esta a imagem logo abaixo do texto `Faça o seu Login`

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h3 class="login-box-msg">Faça o seu Login</h3><br>
      <img src="http://tratspay.com/app/dist/img/logo-trats-mini.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control sty1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control sty1" placeholder="Senha">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">
              Salvar Senha </label>
            <a href="recuperar-senha.html" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Esqueceu a senha?</a> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 m-t-1">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Acessar Conta</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col --> 
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
     
      </div>
    <!-- /.social-auth-links -->
    
    <div class="m-t-2">Ainda não possui uma conta? <a href="criar-conta.html" class="text-center"><strong> Cadastre-se</strong></a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body --> 
</div>
```